# OpenCV cv::imshow() does not work but cvShowImage() does

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having an issue that I've never had with OpenCV before. When I use cv::imshow() the image is shown perfectly, but there are weird ascii characters along the top bar instead of the window name and every few seconds a new window appears with a different name and the old freezes on whatever frame it was currently on. I can exit out of the windows that are frozen but more appear instantly after with different names.  I have used OpenCV before and imshow() has always worked for me.
Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("Sample Program", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;

        imshow("Sample Program", frame);

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I replace imshow() with

```
cvShowImage("Sample Program", cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)frame));
```

It works perfectly.
I just want to know if theres a library issue or something that is causing this issue
I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Comment: just ran your code on cv 2.4.8 and it works without issues!

Comment: A common cause of this problem is linking to debug libraries in release mode, or vice versa. Make sure this isn't the case.

Comment: Use string literal for title. e.g. `string title = "Sample Program";` and then call with this variable.

Comment: Based on what i'm reading elsewhere i'm pretty sure Aurelius is right, but I havent figured out a way to fix it yet

Comment: I also can't show the window when using imshow(). It work prefect when replaced iby cvShowImage() . Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

With that cv it works for me.